# 0MQ in virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, zeromq

I was able to install 0MQ in Ubuntu 12.04 by doing the followinng:
    $ sudo apt-get install libzmq-dev
    $ sudo apt-get install python-zmq

but when I went to use it in a virtualenv it could not find the module. What do I have to do in my virtualenv to see it

Answer (score 3):

Once you make your virtualenv and activate it, use pip to install Python packages.  They will install into your virtualenv.

Alternately, when you create your virtualenv, enable system-wide packages (with the `--system-site-packages` switch) within it so that system-installed packages will be visible in the virtualenv.